# Slash before quotation mark in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Do anyone know how to solve a problem with slash before quotation mark ?? for example, I want to show a text in console that looks like this :

```
"/ Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \"
```

but there is problem with \" console don't like it.

I searched for it in google but didn't find anything...

Comment: Just for your information a "speech mark" is called a "quotation mark" in english.

Answer (score 5):

Backslash is a special character in double quotes. In single quotes, it has not special meaning:

```
echo '"/ Text Text \"'
```

In double quotes, it's used to escape special characters - and it can escape itself:

```
echo "/ Text Text \\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose all your text inside single quotes. Bash won't parse the codes present inside single quotes.

```
echo '"/ Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \"'
```